# Is there a way I can let users access my WebApp using a CNAMErecord on their primary domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, web-applications

I want a way of allowing users to access a whit-label version of my WebApp using a CNAME record allowing them to login to their app from a subdomain or domain they setup.

e.g. ***app.mywebapp.com*** would be where I host the app.

User will access app via **userapp.userdomain.com** or **userdomain.com** by using a cname record pointing to ***app.mywebapp.com.***

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to serve your web application as the default catch-all virtual host or your server needs to be aware of each and every hostname it should serve. The CNAME is a DNS concept, and the web server only sees the HTTP `Host:` header (or SNI in case of HTTPS), which is always the original hostname in the address bar.